# How to make recursive a pl/sql code block which one work with several selects sentences?

Tags: oracle, recursion, plsql

I have a pl/sql code block I'd like to improve. It's the next:

```
                SELECT REPLACE(v_tx_cuerpo, '${param1}', rec.param1)
                  INTO v_tx_cuerpo
                  from DUAL;
                SELECT REPLACE(v_tx_cuerpo, '${param2}', rec.param2)
                  INTO v_tx_cuerpo
                  from DUAL;
                SELECT REPLACE(v_tx_cuerpo, '${param3}', rec.param3)
                  INTO v_tx_cuerpo
                  from DUAL;
                SELECT REPLACE(v_tx_cuerpo, '${param4}', rec.param4)
                  INTO v_tx_cuerpo
                  from DUAL;
                SELECT REPLACE(v_tx_cuerpo, '${param5}', rec.param5)
                  INTO v_tx_cuerpo
                  from DUAL;
```

As you see, it's repetitive. I'll explain it. **v_tx_cuerpo** is a text block which has some similar parameters. I want to replace them for some specific values. Each one of this parameters have names **${param#}** and each one must be replace by one specific value .

What I'd like is, can run it in a loop, make it recursive. Can someone helpme whit this?

Comment: What's your oracle version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't described your `rec` type, so I'll show an example how to make it more independent:

```sql
declare
    type t_rec is record(
        param1 varchar2(30),
        param2 varchar2(30),
        param3 varchar2(30),
        param4 varchar2(30),
        param5 varchar2(30)
        );
    rec t_rec;
    v_tx_cuerpo varchar2(4000);
    
    function f_subst(str varchar2, template varchar2, subst ora_name_list_t) return varchar2
    as
        res varchar2(32767):=str;
    begin
        for i in 1..subst.count loop
            res:=replace(res, replace(template,'%d',i), subst(i));
        end loop;
        return res;
    end;
begin
    v_tx_cuerpo:='p1:${param1};p2:${param2};p3:${param3};p4:${param4};p5:${param5};';
    v_tx_cuerpo:=f_subst(
                    v_tx_cuerpo,
                    '${param%d}',
                    ora_name_list_t('str1','str2','str3','str4','str5')
                    );
    dbms_output.put_line(v_tx_cuerpo);
end;
/
```

as you can see I've created `function f_subst` that takes 3 arguments:

- `str varchar2` - input string for replacement
- `template varchar2` - string mask for replacement, in your example it's `${param%d}`
- `subst ora_name_list_t` - that is a [collection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-266DBF6D-AA74-490C-ADE5-962C10708C2D) defined as `TYPE ora_name_list_t IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2*(ORA_MAX_NAME_LEN+2)+1)`, so you can specify any number of string for replacement. In this example, I've put `str1` to `str5`.

So this function iterates input collection elements and replaces any substrings that match an input template mask with the value from this collection.

Results:

```
p1:str1;p2:str2;p3:str3;p4:str4;p5:str5;
```

And finally using your original `rec`:

```sql
declare
    type t_rec is record(
        param1 varchar2(30),
        param2 varchar2(30),
        param3 varchar2(30),
        param4 varchar2(30),
        param5 varchar2(30)
        );
    rec t_rec;
    v_tx_cuerpo varchar2(4000);
    
    function f_subst(str varchar2, template varchar2, subst ora_name_list_t) return varchar2
    as
        res varchar2(32767):=str;
    begin
        for i in 1..subst.count loop
            res:=replace(res, replace(template,'%d',i), subst(i));
        end loop;
        return res;
    end;
begin
    v_tx_cuerpo:='p1:${param1};p2:${param2};p3:${param3};p4:${param4};p5:${param5};';
    rec.param1:='str1';
    rec.param2:='str2';
    rec.param3:='str3';
    rec.param4:='str4';
    rec.param5:='str5';
    
    v_tx_cuerpo:=f_subst(
                    v_tx_cuerpo,
                    '${param%d}',
                    ora_name_list_t(
                        rec.param1,
                        rec.param2,
                        rec.param3,
                        rec.param4,
                        rec.param5
                        )
                    );
    dbms_output.put_line(v_tx_cuerpo);
end;
/
```

Comment: This is a good solution. If you change your loop to a loop back - from `subst.count` to `1`, then your solution could run for array with length > 10 (with this current loop if you have param11, param12 then those two will all be replaced by param1)

Comment: Thanks you so much for that good answer. And I'm sorry for not see it before. I'll put it in action