# Oracle Remap column name in formula string

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

I have table `tmp_table` like this

```
col_no  col_name
1       col1 
2       text1
3       text2
4       col2 
5       text3
6       col3 
7       col4 
8       col5 
9       col6 
10      col7 
11      col8 
12      col9 
13      col10
14      col11
15      col12
```

and table `calc_table`

```
order_no    formula
1           n7 = n6 + n4 * n1
2           n9 = n7 / n8
```

The expected output is

```
order_no    formula
1           col4 = col3 + col2 * col1
2           col6 = col4 / col5
```

Requirement: remap `col_no` from `nx` to `col_name`: `coly` in `calc_table.formula` base on `tmp_table`

Does someone have a solution for this? I'm trying to find one so that we could do dynamic SQL based on the remapped formula, but I must remap it first.

Comment: You can use a function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/68584438/429100

Comment: Just input `'n%d'` as a second argument and `(select cast(collect(col_name) as varchar2_table) from tmp_table) ` as third argument

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov Thank you, I change your loop in `f_subst` to a loop back - from `subst.count` to `1` and do get my expected result.